# Change the "selected" color of a ListBox in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How do you change that ugly blue color that you get when you select something in a `listbox` in Windows Forms? All of the solutions I was able to find either include re-creating the whole control, or just using WPF. Is there any way to do it within WinForms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `DrawMode` of your listBox to `OwnerDrawFixed` and subscribe to `DrawItem` event:

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ? 
                  Brushes.Red : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
    g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, 
             new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault); 
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();            
}
```

You can determine state of drawing item by checking `e.State` property of event argument. If state is `Selected`, then use whatever brush you like (e.g. Red) to fill item line.

Comment: +1. Interesting approach. For some reason I am seeing the items slightly displaced towards the bottom of expected rectangle. Could it be my custom dpi set at 125%?

Comment: I have the same problem as Neolisk. +1 tho

Comment: You can use this for multiple list boxes by changing "listBox" to ((ListBox)sender). That is, the sender of this method is the list box whose item needs to be drawn.

Answer (score 4):

Before Editing..(he asks about the ListView not the ListBox)

ObjectListView :

```
ListView1.UseCustomSelectionColors = true;
ListView1.HighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Red; // for example :)
ListView1.UnfocusedHighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

ListView :

```
myitem.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Please note that setting BackColor of a ListView item does not solve selection color issue, which OP is asking about.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I met listbox, not listview